# Admob ad not sticking to bottom on scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, view, admob

I've added a admob ad which is placed at the bottom. The problem is when i scroll down in the UITableView the admob does not stay at the bottom. It stays where it started. How can i achieve this:

This is my code:

```
GADBannerView  *bannerView_ = [[GADBannerView alloc] initWithAdSize:kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait];
bannerView_.adUnitID = @"adid";
bannerView_.rootViewController = self;

UIView  *bannerView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,self.view.frame.size.height - bannerView_.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, bannerView_.frame.size.height)];

bannerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
[bannerView addSubview:bannerView_];
[self.view addSubview:bannerView];
[self.view bringSubviewToFront:bannerView];
[bannerView_ loadRequest:[GADRequest request]];
```

Comment: Please don't show stuff like adUnitID here...Regarding your question, I'm assuming self.view is the scrollview, in that case, change self.view into a normal view, add a scrollview inside that view, and add the banner to self.view so that it is outside of the scrollview

Answer (score 0):

Don't add the banner view to your `UITableView` or it will scroll with the content. I'm assuming you're using a `UITableViewController`. You could instead use a standard `UIViewController` subclass with a `UITableView` added to it, where you allow enough space below it for the banner ad. Just make sure you add it to the `UIViewController`'s view, not the `UITableView`.